# Menu Wordpress scroll

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I use performag theme from ThriveTheme and I have problem with the menu for cellphone.

It's a very big menu with a lot of sub-menus. ( It's not mine and I can't change it)

Performag theme use "@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)". But this theme open all sub-menu when you click on the hamburger menu, so if you want the last link in my menu, you have to scroll a lot.

So I changed the file css. Now it's "ok" but I have a trouble when I scroll. I can't scroll until the end.

http://dev.test.babylonradio.com/ You can look on my website with the inspector.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't include any links. Explain your problem here and include what's not working, how it should work, what you have tried and the relevant code.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like this is an css issue. Try to use media query for mobile views.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I use media query. But when I click on my "hamburger menu" and I open a sub-menu I can't scroll all the sub-menu.